# Using Page Url with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've browsed a few other questions on here with getting current page url with jQuery and/or plain javascript but I have been having no luck.

My goal is this: depending on what page the user is on, I want a border under that menu item.
This is how I am attempting to do it:

```
var urlHome = 'http://example.com/'
var urlShop = 'http://example.com/shop/'
var urlTeam = 'http://example.com/team/'

if (document.url.is(urlHome)) {
    $('#home-link').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #000');
}
else if (document.url.is(urlShop)) {
    $('#shop-link').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #000');
}
else if (document.url.is(urlTeam)) {
    $('#team-link').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #000');
};
```

Unfortunately this code isn't working for me, I'm open to any and all suggestions, thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: try `if (document.url == urlHome)` etc.... `.is` is a jquery function

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, and doesn't have an is function.  document.URL === urlHome should work.

Comment: I think you might need document.location.href

Comment: And if you store that in a variable you can pass it like this var _href = document.location.href; if (_href === 'http://example.com/shop/') {execute code etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
if(document.URL == urlHome)
{
// Whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there was a difference between == and .is

Comment: Anytime, Dont forget to mark it as correct answer... Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
var loc = window.location.href,id="";
     if (loc === urlHome) id = "home";
else if (loc === urlShop) id = "shop";
else if (loc === urlTeam) id = "team";
if (id) $('#'+id+'-link').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #000');
```

This works for me, with my own variables of course :)

Comment: Thank you, i thought .is was the same as ===

Comment: Please only load the href once and set css once

Comment: @mplungjan : I'm not 100% sure what that would change. Would copying the href value into a separate variable and checking that instead of the original be better? Feel free to edit the code.

Comment: Ok, changed it to a less verbose version

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to know there's always something one can learn :)